# Console.log not working in a dockerized Node.js / Express app

Tags: node.js, express, docker, dockerfile

I have built a Node.js app within a docker container with the following Dockerfile:

```php
FROM node:carbon

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I am trying to console.log within an express route, however after `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d`, the console is not interactive and logs are not being echoed at all.

```php
'use strict';

// Requires
const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // This isn't being printed anywhere
    console.log(req);
});

// Start
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `-d` from the command you're using to run the container:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080
```

The `-d` option runs the container in the background, so you won't be able to see its output in your console.

If you want to keep the container running in the background and you want to access that container's shell, you can run the following command once your container is up and running:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

Comment: Newbie question: Why doesn't it work if the docker is detached? I thought the Javascript code, including `console.log` was executed locally in the browser not inside the docker.

Comment: Not all javascript is executed in the same runtime environment like the browser. In this case there is javascript running in the node runtime environment which is a server side technology. The docker image used to build this container has node installed on it and the CMD command runs the javascript code with node in the container.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this comment as I was searching for the same thing and this was first result on Google.

```
docker logs <container-name>
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: The command `docker logs` is usefull to see the logs that a container write to stdout. But this is the main issue on the question.